# Different results from UTL_RAW.BIT_AND() and BITAND()

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-function

Can someone explain to me why I get different results:

```
SELECT UTL_RAW.BIT_AND('FFFF', '00') AS test FROM DUAL;

-- result: 00FF (?? It seems he converted my 00 to 00FF, but 00 != 00FF)

SELECT TO_CHAR( BITAND( TO_NUMBER('FFFF', 'XXXX'), TO_NUMBER('00', 'XXXX')), 'XXXX' ) as test FROM DUAL;    

-- result: 0 (as expected)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UTL_RAW operates with left-aligned raw blocks of bytes.
Binary numbers are usually right-aligned.

Comment: I am that far... but why add `1` instead of `0`?

Comment: Tail (beyond minimal length of operands) is just copied.  No `1`s are appended.

Comment: OK, it makes sense. So if my left operand is `RAW(128)` my right operand must also be `RAW(128)`. Bit inconvenient, but OK I guess. This will make the function slow. Nothing to do about it?

Comment: Use `BITAND` for numbers.  It works with 128-bit signed integers.

Comment: Afais `RAW(128)` is 128 _byte_.

Comment: Or use `UTL_RAW.OVERLAY` for correcting trailing zeroes of the result.

Comment: `UTL_RAW.OVERLAY` will do. Thanks!